# Computing the posterior probability in VAE's decoder

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

The decoder layer of a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) is supposed to allow us to sample $x$ given the prior $z$ on the latent layer. In the VAE tutorial on Keras (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py), the code for sampling new digits is

```
# build a digit generator that can sample from the learned distribution
decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
_h_decoded = decoder_h(decoder_input)
_x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(_h_decoded)
generator = Model(decoder_input, _x_decoded_mean)

# display a 2D manifold of the digits
n = 15  # figure with 15x15 digits
digit_size = 28
figure = np.zeros((digit_size * n, digit_size * n))
# linearly spaced coordinates on the unit square were transformed through the inverse CDF (ppf) of the Gaussian
# to produce values of the latent variables z, since the prior of the latent space is Gaussian
grid_x = norm.ppf(np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, n))
grid_y = norm.ppf(np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, n))

for i, yi in enumerate(grid_x):
    for j, xi in enumerate(grid_y):
        z_sample = np.array([[xi, yi]])
        x_decoded = generator.predict(z_sample)
        digit = x_decoded[0].reshape(digit_size, digit_size)
        figure[i * digit_size: (i + 1) * digit_size,
               j * digit_size: (j + 1) * digit_size] = digit

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(figure, cmap='Greys_r')
plt.show()
```

I want to know if there is a way of modifying this code so that given a sample $x$ and a prior $z$ for the latent layer, we can calculate the posterior probability $p(x \mid z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For continuous $X$:

$X|z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu = f(z), \sigma^2)$ where $f$ is the decoder of the network, and $\sigma$ is a hyperparameter of the model.

For discrete $X$:

$X|z \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\mu = f(z))$

Comment: Is $\sigma^2$ the same as the variance of the prior of the latent layer (in this case, 1)?

Comment: @Alex no. It appears as a constant factor multiplier on the reconstruction loss. (Recall the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}$ term in the gaussian. I also added something to my answer for discrete $X$.

Comment: Ahh ok, I think that makes a bit more sense. In my case however, $X$ is a vector, not just a single value. How would that work with the Bernoulli distribution? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, think of it as a vector of bernoulli random variables, and the $i$th one has $\mu_i = f(z)_i$

Comment: It seems very strange though that P(x|z) is not a function of x, and only z...

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer. $X|z$ is a random variable dependent on only $z$. To find $P(X|z)$, you need to evaluate the density of that random variable at $X$.