# Clarification on normal distribution assumption for probablistic decoder P(x|z) in VAE

Tags: autoencoders, variational-bayes

After searching around on the internet, it seems that the following assumption seems to be commonly used in VAEs:

- For a continuous domain (MNIST), assume $p(x|z) = N(x; f(z), \sigma^2)$. Where $f(z)$ is the output of the decoder for a specific pixel value. In practice, we set the variance to some handpicked value. Not sure why.
- For a discrete (MNIST, but binarized), assume $P(x|z) = Bernoulli(x; \theta = f(z))$, where $f(z)$ is the decoder output as before, but specifically passed through a sigmoid to specify a probability.

The Bernoulli assumption sort of makes sense, since the Bernoulli distribution seems to fit the domain of binarized pixels.

However, for the continuous case, why do we assume that $P(x|z)$ is normally distributed? When does this assumption break? Why do we set the variance to some constant rather than having an auxiliary decoder on the latent code for the variance?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for presuming the decoder to be Gaussian is because that makes everything easier without too much constraining your solutions. I have checked the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf?source=post_page), and they do not presume the variance from the decoder to be constant. So an additional auxiliary decoder for the variance is not necessary.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340736/computing-the-posterior-probability-in-vaes-decoder

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368001/is-the-output-of-a-variational-autoencoder-meant-to-be-a-distribution-that-can-b

When you compute the log likelihood of p(x|z) assuming it is distributed normally as written out in my question, you end up with both $\sigma$ and $\mu$ terms inside the result. The comment chains in the answers for the two questions I linked above seem to suggest that you can just set the variance to be a fixed value during optimization.

Comment: This confuses me because in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf in section C2 of the original VAE for gaussian MLP as a decoder, I think they have two sets of weights and biases that operate on the latent, one to compute the log variance and another to compute the mean.